# How can a one-entry git repo be in detached head status?

Tags: git, version-control

My understanding of detached HEAD in git : You have checked out an old version of your code without making a branch. If you attempt to commit new code, you will be creating a new commit with a link back to the old version, and that will be your head for the moment. The "detached" part refers to the fact that you have lost changes because there is no branch indicating the existence of the newer commits. If you commit something new, the new-new changes will show up in the log but the old-new changes will not. Ugh, I am confusing. Illustrated :

```
A->B(HEAD)
'git checkout A'
A (DETACHED HEAD)
'write a video game'
'git commit'
A->C(HEAD)
/// And B is lost unless you know how to scour the raw git objects for trees
```

Now here is the status of my repo:

```
  ? git log --all --oneline --graph --decorate
* 3c43b31 (HEAD, master) Original site files

  ? git status
HEAD detached at 3c43b31
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    page.html
    page.css
```

Confession: This is the status right after I tried reverting all my changes back to the one existing commit using 'checkout .' and then using 'checkout 3c43b31', neither of which worked.

Question : Why is HEAD detached? There is only one commit, and we are sitting on it.

Question : Why didn't my checkouts work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My understanding of detached HEAD in git : You have checked out an old version of your code without making a branch.

This is sort-of-right.  It's wrong in technical detail, which starts to matter in your own situation.

The precise definition of the "detached HEAD" state is that the name `HEAD` becomes a pointer to a specific commit ID, rather than containing a *branch name*.

A branch name itself is *always* a pointer to a specific commit ID.  This name points to the *tip commit* on that branch (which is a bit silly since this is just the definition of the tip commit: it's the one the branch name points-to).  That is:

> ```
> A->B(HEAD)
> ```

is *close* but not quite right.  What we have is instead:

```
              HEAD
               |
               v
A <- B   <-- master
```

That is, `HEAD` points to `master`, and `master` points to `B` (not to `A`).  And, although it seems backwards (and most of the time you don't need to care anyway), the second commit `B` points back to the first commit `A`, rather than vice-versa.

With a detached HEAD, we simply point HEAD directly to the commit:

```
    HEAD
     |
     v
A <- B   <-- master
```

so this can occur whenever there is at least one commit (there needs to be *some* commit for all these names to point-to).

The `git checkout` command is the one that sets `HEAD`.  When you ask it to:

```
git checkout master
```

it sets `HEAD` to point to `master`, without changing `master` itself at all.  But when you give it a raw commit-ID (as in checking out an older commit), *or the `--detach` flag*, it sets `HEAD` to point directly to the commit, instead of pointing HEAD to the branch-name.

> ```
> A (DETACHED HEAD)
> 'write a video game'
> 'git commit'
> A->C(HEAD)
> /// And B is lost unless you know how to scour the raw git objects for trees
> ```

Again, this is pretty close to correct—but the arrows point the other way (which is pretty minor), and `B` is not lost at all (which is pretty major), because `master` still points to it:

```
    B   <-- master
  /
A
  \
    C   <-- HEAD
```

The problem now is that if you use `git checkout master`, it is commit `C` that becomes lost.  (The secret place to find it is in the reflog for `HEAD`, but this is still a pain in the keister.)

When you are in this state, using `git checkout -b newname`, or `git branch newname`, will create a new branch named `newname`, pointing to commit `C`:

```
    B   <-- master
  /
A
  \
    C   <-- newname
```

The difference between using `git checkout -b` and `git branch` has, of course, to do with `HEAD`:

```
git checkout -b newname
```

changes `HEAD` to point to the new branch:

```
    B   <-- master
  /
A
  \
    C   <-- newname
              ^
              |
             HEAD
```

Using `git branch` to create the name leaves `HEAD` detached:

```
    B   <-- master
  /
A
  \
    C   <-- newname
    ^
    |
   HEAD
```

So, again, "detached HEAD" just means "HEAD points straight to a commit, without detouring through a branch name first."

Answer (score 1):

Generally `git checkout <sha1>` makes a detached HEAD. You could consider a detached HEAD a nameless branch. Other commands like `git rebase --onto <sha1> <sha1A> <sha1B>` can result in a detached HEAD because this command runs `git checkout <sha1B>` internally.

In your case, `B` is not lost. If you were on a branch, you could run `git checkout <branch>` to restore. A detached HEAD is a nameless branch and your previous branch that points to B is still there, so you can use `git checkout` to switch between these 2 branches. If you were on a detached HEAD, you could run `git reflog` or `git log -g` to find `B`'s sha1 back.